# add section header date in a listview populated from sqlite

Tags: android, listview

I'm having a list view populated from sqlite with different data. I use a Simple Adapter to populate the list. Here is my code how I populate the list:

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = controller.getOld();
            // If users exists in SQLite DB
            if (userList.size() != 0) {


                // Set the User Array list in ListView
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(OldTips.this, userList, R.layout.old_tips, new String[] {
 "userId", "tara","ora_meci" ,"echipa_acasa","echipa_deplasare","cota","explicatii","rezultat","pauza","final"}, new int[] { R.id.userId, R.id.tara , R.id.ora_meci, R.id.echipa_acasa, R.id.echipa_deplasare, R.id.cota,R.id.explicatii,R.id.rezultat,R.id.pauza,R.id.finall});
                final ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                m
                myList.setAdapter(adapter);


            }
```

Is there a way, on this particular way of populate a list view, to add section headers and each section header to be a date which I get from the sqlite? I walk through other solutions but didn't find a way to achieve it...